# Unity AndroidJavaObject pass float array as out parameter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, android-unity-plugin

I have this Java Method

```
public class Test {
  double calculate(float[] array){
    array[0] = 2.0f;
    return 3.0f;
  }
}
```

I integrated this Java Method via an Android Archive into Unity. I access this method like this:

```
var javaObject = new AndroidJavaObject("Test");
float[] inOut = new float[1];
double res = javaObject.Call<double>("calculate", inOut);
```

Now, the res variable holds the value 3.0f as expected. But the inOut array does still have 0 at index position 0, but it should have 2.0f;

How do I properly pass a primitives array to Java code from Unity and use it as an "inOut" argument?

Thank you

Comment: Well, you should rethink your code. The float is passed as a copy, so only the copy gets modified, while the original inOut array remains unchanged. Perhaps you should create 2  methods, one that returns double and another one that returns an array. Of course I don't know what is your use case and what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: As far as I know both Java and C# use "Call by reference". Thus the object (= float[]) I pass to the method should not be copied but directly used. I verified this behavior with an quick test in both C# and Java.

Comment: Clearly that doesn't happen in this situation. When communicating between C# and Java you are getting a copy. I'm not sure if there is a way to do what you want but there are clearly solutions to work around it.